R console could not find function "get_type_prob"
I am working through the book Integrated Inferences which uses the R library CausalQueries to perform example calculations.
As the title describes, a number of other CausalQueries functions are working well, but I get an error that says "could not find function "get_type_prob."
I installed R 4.4 for windows yesterday and installed the CausalQueries library in a user-specific folder (because the R package manager couldn't add it to the system installation.  I load it into the workspace with library(CausalQueries), verify it appears in search() results, and the first few function calls to other library functions work.
Working through this example, pasting it in an expression at a time:
`model <- make_model("X -> M -> Y") |>
         set_restrictions("X[]==0") |>
         set_restrictions("M[X=1] < M[X=0]") |>
         set_restrictions("Y[M=1] < Y[M=0]")   

q1 <- "Y[X = 1] > Y[X = 0]"
q2 <- "X == 1 & Y == 1"

df <- data.frame(
  a1 = get_query_types(model, q1)$types,
  a2 = get_query_types(model, q2)$types,
  p  = get_type_prob(model))`

I expected this to work and give the data that informs the table in the CausalQueries docs.
Full session:
> library(CausalQueries)
Loading required package: dplyr

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Loading required package: Rcpp
> model <- make_model("X -> M -> Y") |>
+          set_restrictions("X[]==0") |>
+          set_restrictions("M[X=1] < M[X=0]") |>
+          set_restrictions("Y[M=1] < Y[M=0]")   
> 
> q1 <- "Y[X = 1] > Y[X = 0]"
> q2 <- "X == 1 & Y == 1"
> 
> df <- data.frame(
+   a1 = get_query_types(model, q1)$types,
+   a2 = get_query_types(model, q2)$types,
+   p  = get_type_prob(model))
Error in get_type_prob(model) : could not find function "get_type_prob"

> ls("package:CausalQueries")
 [1] "collapse_data"           "complements"            
 [3] "data_type_names"         "decreasing"             
 [5] "democracy_data"          "draw_causal_type"       
 [7] "expand_data"             "expand_wildcard"        
 [9] "get_all_data_types"      "get_event_probabilities"
[11] "get_query_types"         "grab"                   
[13] "increasing"              "institutions_data"      
[15] "interacts"               "interpret_type"         
[17] "lipids_data"             "make_data"              
[19] "make_events"             "make_model"             
[21] "make_parameters"         "make_parameters_df"     
[23] "make_prior_distribution" "make_priors"            
[25] "non_decreasing"          "non_increasing"         
[27] "observe_data"            "plot_model"             
[29] "query_distribution"      "query_model"            
[31] "realise_outcomes"        "set_confound"           
[33] "set_parameter_matrix"    "set_parameters"         
[35] "set_prior_distribution"  "set_priors"             
[37] "set_restrictions"        "simulate_data"          
[39] "substitutes"             "te"                     
[41] "update_model"


Could you please post the exact error? (verbatim copy or screenshot)? Assuming what you are posting is verbatim, there is no dot in the error message so it looks like you typed it with dot. In the meantime, make sure that the provided code is a Minimal Reproducible Example. https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example

If you run sessionInfo() after library(CausalQueries), what version of the package does it say you are running?

Thanks for the list, looks like there isn't get_type_prob in the currently installed package. Try to reinstall the package with install.packages(CausalQueries), then restart R and try to rerun the code.
If even that doesn't work, do the same with install.packages("remotes"); remotes::install_github("https://github.com/integrated-inferences/CausalQueries/") to pull the latest dev version (in case you were downloading some old binary from CRAN instead).

One more peek into the code. Looks like there is nothing wrong with your installation. get_type_prob is marked as internal, it is not exported, see: https://github.com/integrated-inferences/CausalQueries/blob/master/R/get_type_prob.R#L9

Looks like get_type_prob is not an exported function.
Probably the package was updated after the book was written and no automatic checks were performed.
What is strange is that the manual on CRAN still contains all the internal functions. That typically shouldn't happen. CRAN should complain when you try to make documentation for internal functions, and when you mark Roxygen2 comments with @internal, the man files for that function should not be created.
See: https://github.com/integrated-inferences/CausalQueries/blob/master/R/get_type_prob.R#L9
I see that you have already asked on git. Good job!
